# What will happen when multiple clients try to change a state variable simultaneously in a solidity contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

For databases like MySQL, we have locks for data consistency, when 2 clients try to look up a value and update it, I can use locks to make sure the second client always wait for the first client finish its operation.

Is there any mechanisms for ethereum/solidity like locks for data consistency? If not, what will happen if I have a contract on ethereum:

```
contract MyContract{
    string name;
    function changeName(string memory newName) public view{
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

When address A calling changeName("name1") and address B calling changeName("name2") at the same time? What will be the value of state variable "name"?

Answer (score 0):

The EVM executes all transactions in series, not in parallel.

Actual order in which are the transactions executed within a block depends on the miner (PoW) or validator (PoS) of that specific block. However in most cases they simply order from largest `gasPrice` to smallest.

Also note that the `view` modifier disallows this function to change the contract state. But if you omit the modifier, the above applies.